# Query into array with mongoose returns empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need search for specific ids in array field using mongoose and mongodb.
I am using the next code but the results is always an empty array:

What am I doing wrong?

//model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const ObjectId=mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const modelosAnamneseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nome:{type:String, unique:true},
    perguntasAtivas:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Perguntadeanamnese'}],
});
```

//pergunta de anamnese model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const perguntasAnamneseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nome:{type:String, unique:true},
    tipopergunta:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'TipoPerguntaAnamnese'},
    ativo:{type:Boolean},
    temObservacao:{type:Boolean},
    observacao:{type:String},
    created_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
    altered_at:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Perguntadeanamnese', perguntasAnamneseSchema,'perguntasdeanamnese' );
```

//data sample:

```
{'name':'test',
'perguntasAtivas':[
{_id: "5915bec7813317eaabd9897e", id: 2, nome: "Diabetes"},
{_id: "5915bec7813317eaabd98981", id: 5, nome: "Remédio de uso contínuo"},
{_id: "5915bec7813317eaabd9897d", id: 1, nome: "Alergias"},
{_id: "5915bec7813317eaabd98984", id: 8, nome: "Etilismo"}
]
```

//query for id="5915bec7813317eaabd9897d"

```
const query={'perguntasAtivas._id': new ObjectId(req.params.id)};
ModeloAnamnese.find(query)
.exec( (err,data) => {
   callback(err,data,res)
})
```

Here,the query returns  empty array

Comment: The schema does not match the data. The schema is expecting a plain array of `ObjectId` as in `perguntasAtivas:[ObjectId("5915bec7813317eaabd9897e"),ObjectId("5915bec7813317eaabd98981")]`. At a guess you would appear to have defined a separate model where you should have defined as embedded schema, since that is how the data is actually stored.

Comment: Sorry, the data showing is using populate. When  using populate('perguntasAtivas'), I get this results. If you want I can post the model to "perguntasdeanamnese"

Comment: Then take a firm guess at why your query fails. This is pretty simple and I'm pretty sure you've been pointed at the frequent duplicate before.

Comment: Thanks Mr Neil, I found the problem. The coorect query is query={'perguntasAtivas': new ObjectId(req.params.id)};